# rxplot is not plotting as desired

Tags: ros, rxplot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to use  [rxplot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxplot). I have a topic called  pose3D_LD defined somewhere in my code and the related fields are as below:

```
        pose3D_LD.position.x = utmRight_x;
        pose3D_LD.position.y = utmHigh_y;
        pose3D_LD.position.z = data_set[t][5]; 

        pose3D_LD.orientation.x = q.x();
        pose3D_LD.orientation.y = q.y();
        pose3D_LD.orientation.z = q.z();
        pose3D_LD.orientation.w = q.w();
```

However, when I issue a command, say, *rxplot /pose3D_LD/position.x*, it returns an error saying that *plotting topics /pose3D_LD/position.x
Invalid topic spec [/pose3D_LD/position.x]: 'Pose' object has no attribute 'position.x'*. Can someone check the command I call, whether it is valid or not? I guess, the topic and field is set correctly, but I'm not sure if the dot operator is allowed or not upon calling that command.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12342/rxplot-is-not-plotting-as-desired/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Very sorry to answer this myself, I just found the hint [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/143/rxplot-for-vector-like-types).

Dot operator is not allowed, instead, we need to use slash(/).

---

Originally posted by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0